# Is it possible to use psycopg2 with IronPython in a Windows Form app?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, psycopg2

I built a Windows Form to gather information about projects. This information is then uploaded to a database.

Actually, I'm using a Python script to do that (the required information is therefore hardcoded in the script by the user).

I would like to use my WindowsForm to set the variable for my script. I'm getting an IronPython runtime exception : `cannot import _psycopg from psycopg2`

Here's the code that set up the variables and run the script:

```
 private void btn_uploaddata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            engine.SetSearchPaths(new Collection<string>(new[]
            {
                @"C:\Python27_XY",
                @"C:\Python27_XY\DLLs",
                @"C:\Python27_XY\Lib",
                @"C:\Python27_XY\Lib\site-packages",
            }));

            scope.SetVariable("project_num", tb_projnum.Text);
            scope.SetVariable("project_name", tb_projname.Text);
            scope.SetVariable("proj_client", tb_projclient.Text);

            engine.ExecuteFile(@"path/to/script.py", scope);
        }
```

Is it only possible to use psycopg2 with IronPython ?

Comment: you can also try pythonnet

Answer (score 2):

The psycopg2 module uses a CPython extension and will therefore not work with IronPython. There is an experimental [ctypes version](https://github.com/mvantellingen/psycopg2-ctypes) which is no longer supported by the author.

In any case, you need to install the according package. Did you actually try this?

```
ipy.exe -X:Frames -m pip psycopg2
```

If pip is not found you have to ensure pip first.

```
ipy.exe -X:Frames -m ensurepip
```